# What happend to project in global.json

Tags: asp.net-core

I've just taken on a .Net Core application. I've found it has a global.json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

The [documentation for the global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file makes no mention of a `projects` key. What does it mean? Is it obsolete? If so what should I replace it with?

Answer (score 4):

Since the move to MSBUILD, `global.json` is only used to explicitly specify the SDK version to use.

You may reference the projects from a solution file instead. Eg:

```sh
dotnet new sln
dotnet sln add path/to/project.csproj
```